# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Authentication::Login#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I am on windows machine and using Rails 6.0.3.1 . I have installed react using command `rails webpacker:install:react`. i have started webpack-dev-server successfully and it is compiling all the files as shown below.

[image]

But whenever i am refreshing my page http://localhost:3000/login i am getting below error.

```
Webpacker can't find hello_react.jsx in C:/Users/sanjay.salunkhe/SellAnything/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-8b57fc2151de01963297.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-8b57fc2151de01963297.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-8b57fc2151de01963297.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-8b57fc2151de01963297.js.map"
      ]
    },
    "hello_react": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/hello_react-4532b032a8e50c80f4dc.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/hello_react-4532b032a8e50c80f4dc.js.map"
      ]
    }
  },
  "hello_react.js": "/packs/js/hello_react-4532b032a8e50c80f4dc.js",
  "hello_react.js.map": "/packs/js/hello_react-4532b032a8e50c80f4dc.js.map"
}
```

See my Below webpacker.yml file content

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: false

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

see below babel.config.js file content.

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  var validEnv = ['development', 'test', 'production']
  var currentEnv = api.env()
  var isDevelopmentEnv = api.env('development')
  var isProductionEnv = api.env('production')
  var isTestEnv = api.env('test')

  if (!validEnv.includes(currentEnv)) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please specify a valid `NODE_ENV` or ' +
        '`BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", ' +
        '"test", and "production". Instead, received: ' +
        JSON.stringify(currentEnv) +
        '.'
    )
  }

  return {
    presets: [
      isTestEnv && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          },
          modules: 'commonjs'
        },
        '@babel/preset-react'
      ],
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol']
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/preset-react',
        {
          development: isDevelopmentEnv || isTestEnv,
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean),
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-macros',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      isTestEnv && 'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        {
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          helpers: false,
          regenerator: true,
          corejs: false
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        {
          async: false
        }
      ],
      isProductionEnv && [
        'babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        {
          removeImport: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean)
  }
}
```

I am not sure why i am getting error `Webpacker can't find hello_react.jsx in C:/Users/sanjay.salunkhe/SellAnything/public/packs/manifest.json` . can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found issue in my application.html.erb file. i was calling hello_react file with extension .jsx as shown below.

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'hello_react.jsx' %>
```

changing it to below works.

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'hello_react' %>
```